# Connect UWP C# application to Azure SQL Database MFA?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp, azure-sql-database

I have a blank UWP C# application that I would like to connect to an Azure SQL database using MFA.
Targeting version: Win10 version 1903 build 18362
Min version: Win10 Fall Creators Update build 16299

I've attempted to use references like System.Data.SqlClient/Microsoft.IdentityMode.Clients.
But my application does not like the reference. When clicking into it, it tells me the project cannot be viewed in the object browser. I tried reinstalling it different ways with no luck. Also downloaded all the recent Windows 10 SDK versions.
[reference error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxjts.png)

Whats the best approach to this and if anyone has resources that could help me out.

Comment: hi sluu-hou, our team member has replied your [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/5621/how-to-get-uwp-to-connect-to-an-azure-sql-database.html) in Microsoft Q&A please pay attention to the following update.